# Netsuite Create Record - No records Created

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Trying to configure a record creation script in Netsuite.
Just getting to grips with the basics.

I have created this script from the Netsuite docs with slight modification to make it relevant to my account.

It runs and says Complete, however no transaction is created and in the logs where I am trying to capture to document number it says 'To be generated'.

I followed all the oracle docs on this so not sure, any help appreciated.

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ScheduledScript
*/

define(['N/runtime', 'N/record'], function(runtime, record) {
    return {
        execute: function(context) {
          var objRecord = record.create({
          type: record.Type.INVOICE, 
          isDynamic: true,
          defaultValues: {
          entity: 3413
    }
});
            objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'location',
            value: 1
        });
        
        objRecord.selectNewLine({
           sublistId: 'item'
        });
            objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'item',
            value: 190
        });
        
            objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'quantity',
            value: 2
        });
            objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'rate',
            value: 2
        });
        
        var documentNum = objRecord.getValue({
            fieldId: 'tranid'
            
        });
            
                log.debug({
                    title: 'New Invoice', 
                    details: 'Record creation progress' + documentNum
                });
            
         }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do objRecord.save() first, then the record will be saved and the tranid will be generated

Comment: Thank you Brian. I did that and the script failed - "You must enter at least one line item for this transaction.","id":"","stack":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)" - Do I need to add another item sublist action to save the sublist first?

Comment: See @Krypton answer, I missed that you didn't commit the line, as that is req'd as well when you are dynamic mode.

Comment: Thank you for your help Brian. Interestingly the record is now creating, which is great, but the tranid still says 'to be generated' - I wonder if this is one of those situations where I need to load the record I have just created in order to get the id?

Comment: Sorry Brian, if you do read this, tranid is still saying 'to be generated' even though the record is being saved.

Comment: @TheIronKing post the updated code

Answer (score 2):

You will need to save the record first (`objRecord.save()`) before a record is saved to the database, or a `tranid` is generated.  Also, before you do that, you will need to make sure there is an item line on the transaction.  As you are using Dynamic Mode functions (`getCurrent...` and `setCurrent...`) to add values to the item line(s) you will also need to *commit* the line(s) before saving:

```
objRecord.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
});
```